# django orm group by json key in json field

Tags: python, json, django, postgresql

I'm using json field on my django model:

```
class JsonTable(models.Model):
    data = JSONField()
    type = models.IntegerField()
```

I tried next query, which works for normal sql fields:

```
JsonTable.objects.filter(type=1).values('type').annotate(Avg('data__superkey'))
```

But this throws next error:

```
FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'superkey' into field. Join on 'data' not permitted.
```

**Is there way to make group by on json key, using Django ORM or some python lib, without use of raw sql?**

Versions: Django 1.9b, PostgreSQL 9.4

**UPDATE**

Example 2:

```
JsonTable.objects.filter(type=1).values('data__happykey').annotate(Avg('data_superkey'))
```

throws same error on `happykey`

Answer (score 2):

After some researching I found next solution:

```
from django.db.models import Count
from django.contrib.postgres.fields.jsonb import KeyTextTransform

superkey = KeyTextTransform('superkey', 'data')
table_items = JsonTable.objects.annotate(superkey = superkey).values('superkey').annotate(Count('id')).order_by()
```

I did not sure about order_by(), but [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/aggregation/#interaction-with-default-ordering-or-order-by) says that is needed.
For another aggregation function type casting needed:

```
from django.db.models import IntegerField
from django.db.models.functions import Cast
superkey = Cast(KeyTextTransform('superkey', 'data'), IntegerField())
```

I test with another model, hope that write this code without misprints. PostgreSQL 9.6, Django 2.07

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this package https://github.com/bradjasper/django-jsonfield,
there is nothing in the code for managing such simulated related queries (*data__some_json_key*)
As Json data is text, you will have to go to raw sql or better : use queryset `extra()` method, but parsing Json in sql seems to be difficult.